Hair curves looks weird
I've watched the some tutorials about new hair system and tried to make same way. But i failed. They switch curve display to strip in the render settings before adding hair, but it looks different on me. What am I doing wrong? İn strand hair looks thin and rounded.


hair curves have a large radius by default for real-world sized humans. In the Asset Browser there are Geometry Nodes (GN) assets for hair. Look for the Set Hair Curve Profile and drag it on the Curves object. It will add a GN modifier. In the its settings you can define the radius for the hair.
